# how to implement top tab bar for an iphone/ipad application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want like a firefox like multi-tab application for iOS
what would be a good practice?
The user should able to create new tab and close existing ones
are there any existing framework to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to roll your own. For a start, I'd suggest adding [UIButtons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) to a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).